# RSS feed validation in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, rss

I have RSS feed on my site. I have validated it by W3C validator and got a strange result.

```
This feed is valid, but interoperability with the widest range of feed readers could be improved by implementing the following recommendations.
line 13, column 45: Problematical RFC 822 date-time value: Fri, 08 Sep 17 14:05:57 +0000
```

I would fix this recommendation. I'm generating date like `date(DATE_RFC822)` in PHP. What can be a problem?

I have tried different ways like `date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000')`, `date('r')` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that the validator is complaining about, is that that DATE_RFC822 only outputs the last two digits of the year.

PHP has the constant `DATE_RSS` built in, which you could use instead.

```
print date(DATE_RSS)
```

Outputs:

> Fri, 08 Sep 2017 16:23:05 +0200

Comment: I tried this one too. The same result.

This feed is valid, but interoperability with the widest range of feed readers could be improved by implementing the following recommendations.
line 13, column 47: Implausible date: Fri, 08 Sep 2017 15:22:17 +0000 [help]

Comment: @VladymyrHrychenko Is your server time correct? "15:22:17 +0000" means that it is 15:22 in the GMT time zone. However, at the time of your posting, it was only 15:11 GMT. Thus, "implausible date" means it is set too far in the future.

Comment: it was a problem. My server had the future date. Thank you a lot!